# [r][network][sna]How to hide the output of the component.dist () function

Tags: r

How to hide the output result when using the following sna::component.dist () function?

```
g<-sna::rgraph(20,tprob=0.05)   #Generate a sparse random graph
g1 <- sna::component.dist(g)
```

Node 1, Reach 2, Total 2
Node 2, Reach 1, Total 3
Node 3, Reach 13, Total 16
Node 4, Reach 4, Total 20
Node 5, Reach 5, Total 25
Node 6, Reach 2, Total 27
Node 7, Reach 1, Total 28
Node 8, Reach 1, Total 29
Node 9, Reach 1, Total 30
Node 10, Reach 5, Total 35
Node 11, Reach 1, Total 36
Node 12, Reach 5, Total 41
Node 13, Reach 14, Total 55
Node 14, Reach 8, Total 63
Node 15, Reach 7, Total 70
Node 16, Reach 3, Total 73
Node 17, Reach 5, Total 78
Node 18, Reach 5, Total 83
Node 19, Reach 1, Total 84
Node 20, Reach 5, Total 89

Comment: I do net get any output when using the function? But if you do, the invisible() function will supress any output.

Comment: I was on the same problem, but I did not understand the solution.
I decided to use `igraph :: components ()` using data of igraph class.
`igraph::graph.adjacency(g) %>% igraph::components()` can get similar result.